# Have macro in separate workbook to locate workbook, copy and paste as values from worksheet into new workbook and save in original workbook's location

Tags: vba, excel

As pre-warning, I am new to using VBA.

I have scraped together the following code to do the following:
1. Locate the worksheet "Intrastat"
2. Copy the used range of this worksheet
3. Paste as values into a new workbook
4. Reformat dates in column B
5. Save the workbook with in the original workbook's location.

However this only works when I have the macro saved in the original workbook. What I need is to be able to have the macro saved in a different workbook and on running the macro I need to be able to select the "original" workbook from a file location on my HDD.

Any ideas?

The Current Code:

```
Sub TB_Intrastat_Data_Cleanse()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set TWKB = ThisWorkbook
Set sel = Selection

Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path

TWKB.Sheets("Intrastat").UsedRange.Copy
wb.Sheets(1).[a1].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

nme = "TB Intrastat Data " & Range("A3") & " MTD"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=folderPath & nme

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Application.GetOpenFilename()` to prompt the user to browse through the file explorer, and open a file.  It will then use that file as `TWKB`:

```
Sub TB_Intrastat_Data_Cleanse()
Dim wb As Workbook, TWKB As Workbook
Dim sel As Range
Dim nme As String

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set TWKB = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose a file to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")
Set sel = Selection

Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path

TWKB.Sheets("Intrastat").UsedRange.Copy
wb.Sheets(1).[a1].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

nme = "TB Intrastat Data " & Range("A3") & " MTD"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=folderPath & nme

End Sub
```

Note: I would change `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` at the end to a workbook variable (or explicitly name the workbook), since you're using two separate ones you want to make sure it's saving the correct one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The only issue I'm facing is that I get "Run-time error '424': Object required" on the line   Set TWKB = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose a file to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files .xls (.xls),")

Comment: @AKendall did you add the workbook declaration? Note I added `Dim TWKB as Workbokk`